# Implement 10 different ways for f(1) and f(-1) to return -1 and 1 respectively

Tags: javascript

I just had a recent challenge to Implement 10 different ways for f(1) and f(-1) to return -1 and 1 respectively

I could only think of 3. Was curious if someone can help me find more solutions for this.

```js
// Implement 10 different ways for f(1) and f(-1) to return -1 and 1 respectively
// Note: The implementation should have logical difference. Sytactical difference will not be considered as a solution
// input can be either 1 or - 1
function f1(input) {
  return input * -1;
}
console.log(f1(1)); // -1
console.log(f1(-1)); // 1

function f2(input) {
  if (input === 1) return -1;
  else if (input === -1) return 1;
}
console.log(f2(1)); // -1
console.log(f2(-1)); // 1

function f3(input) {
  const arr = [null, -1];
  return arr.indexOf(input);
}
console.log(f3(1)); // -1
console.log(f3(-1)); // 1

function f4(input) {}
console.log(f4(1)); // -1
console.log(f4(-1)); // 1

function f5(input) {}
console.log(f5(1)); // -1
console.log(f5(-1)); // 1

function f6(input) {}
console.log(f6(1)); // -1
console.log(f6(-1)); // 1

function f7(input) {}
console.log(f7(1)); // -1
console.log(f7(-1)); // 1

function f8(input) {}
console.log(f8(1)); // -1
console.log(f8(-1)); // 1

function f9(input) {}
console.log(f9(1)); // -1
console.log(f9(-1)); // 1

function f10(input) {}
console.log(f10(1)); // -1
console.log(f10(-1)); // 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few

```
input => -Math.sign(input)
```

```
input => -input
```

```
input => {
  const str = String(input);
  return Number(
    str.startsWith('-') ? str.slice(1) : '-' + str
  );
}
```

```
input => String(input).length === 2 ? 1 : -1
```

```
input => input > 0 ? -1 : 1
```

Comment: A few more:
 `input -1 * -1 - 1`,`input / -1`, `input -1 ? 1 : -1`

Comment: More: `input => -Math.pow(input, 3)`,  `input => -1/input`

Comment: `input => input * ~0`, `input => input / ~0`

Comment: @qrsngky the cube returns the same

Comment: `input => -1 - (1 ^ input)`